# Excel macro working most of the time but not always

Tags: excel, vba

I've made the following macro (explanation bellow):

```
Sub SupprimeContratsExpirés()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    If IsDate(Cells(i, 9)) Then
        If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i - 1, 2) Or Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i + 1, 2) Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            i = i - 1
        End If  
    End If   
    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

The macro is looping until it finds an empty cell in the first column. Finding an empty cell mean the end of the macro.
In the loop, there is a first condition which check if there is a date (end of contract) in the column 9 of the corresponding row.
If there is a date, I want this line to be deleted ONLY if the person represented by the line is represented by another line. That is the second if statement. It checks if the data in column 2 (a number associated to a specific worker) is the same that the data just below or just above. If it is the case, the current line is deleted and my index is decremented (to stay at the same line number because it is incremented later).

It is working most of the time BUT sometimes Excel tells me there is an incompatibility of type on the line of my second if statement...

Could anybody explain me why?

Comment: What's error number? If it's 13 - check this: [Type mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-mismatch-error-13)

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake! The problem was that i replaced a title with a formula that sometimes made a ref error because of the deletion of some lines :)